# Is the Oracle data provider necessary to make a connection to Oracle?

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

Is the Oracle data provider for .NET vital to make a connection to an Oracle database from ASP.NET?.

Is there any other way to make connection with ASP.NET without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET supports the `System.Data.OracleClient` by default, the Microsoft implementation of a .NET provider for Oracle, which on it's turn calls OCI (Oracle Client). Microsoft indicated this provider is deprecated and that a future versions of .NET will not contain it any more.

You also have the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`, often referred to as ODP.NET, which is the Oracle implementation of a .NET provider. It uses OCI too.

For these versions you don't only need the .NET data provider installed, but the Oracle Client tools too, which is quite some work and in my experience, versions will differ over time, so a lot of maintenance is required to keep them aligned.

Since some time, Oracle has a fully managed version of ODP.NET, which doesn't need the Oracle Client to be installed. This seems the easiest available option out now. Just include that in your project, and you are ready to go. There is no dependency whatsoever, so upgrades have become so easy.

Comment: so i am taking your point as that when i installed oracle database it has already ODP.net included ??

Comment: Yes, it has, but the client machines don't. And it is very likely that the database odp.net version differs from client machine 1 and 2. So you have to build a specific version of your product to work with odp.net version X.

Comment: just another question , they have already asked too much on stack over flow . i am facing an error while making connection to oracle 10gR2 of asp.net  . the error no is  "ORA 12154" something about TNx could resolve the connect identifier. If you could guide me to solve this problem It matters a lot  . thnx

Comment: It has to do with an invalid tnsnames.ora configuration. Check that file.

Answer (score 0):

No there are others.

I recommend you try Devart dotConnect. It is an alternative fully managed driver, and also wraps other providers as well as OCI, but it specifically handles different versions and eases deployment over the standard Oracle stuff. I do not work for them, but I use their providers in my tools.

There is also a fully managed ADO.NET provider from Unisys/DataDirect that is much more pricey.